Pyspark with liquid clustering
I have an existing dataframe stored in Azure storage.  How can I enable liquid clustering on it?
I tried doing something this:
df.write.format("delta") \
    .option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .clusterBy("somecol") \
    .save(azure_url)

But got an error saying:
AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'clusterBy'

Is it possible to modify an existing dataframe using pyspark (or even delta lake api)?
Thanks in advance.

What Databricks Runtime are you using? Liquid Clustering through DataFrame APIs is available in Databricks Runtime 14.2 and above.

I am not on Databricks.  Just using Spark 3.5.1 with deltalake jars installed.

You can enable liquid clustering on an existing unpartitioned Delta table using the following syntax:
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
CLUSTER BY (<clustering_columns>)

Check Azure docs for more details on liquid clustering.

As mentioned here:

In Databricks Runtime 14.2 and above, you can use DataFrame APIs and DeltaTable API in Python or Scala to enable liquid clustering.

And you can do it as follows:
# Create an empty table
(DeltaTable.create()
  .tableName("table1")
  .addColumn("col0", dataType = "INT")
  .addColumn("col1", dataType = "STRING")
  .clusterBy("col0")
  .execute())

# Using a CTAS statement
df = spark.read.table("table1")
df.write.format("delta").clusterBy("col0").saveAsTable("table2")

# CTAS using DataFrameWriterV2
df = spark.read.table("table1")
df.writeTo("table1").using("delta").clusterBy("col0").create()


Thank you for you response.  Let me try to be clearer about what I am trying to do: 
delta_table_path = "abfss://your-container@your-account.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/delta-table"
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)


given that i already have the df, how can I issue one of the cluster by statements listed in the documentation?

The first code block (ALTER TABLE command) is doing that only. You need to apply liquid clustering on your existing delta table right? You can just run that command using spark.sql() as follows: spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE delta.`{delta_table_path}` CLUSTER BY (somecol)")

Thank you for this additional info.  I had actually tried this as well but I get the following error: error is
AnalysisException: [DELTA_ALTER_TABLE_CLUSTER_BY_NOT_ALLOWED] ALTER TABLE CLUSTER BY is supported only for Delta table with clustering.
